# Retrieve File from AWS - security issue - URL is being exposed

Tags: amazon-web-services

When a user request a file from the web application. we would like to get the stream from AWS and directly write it to the client folder..

Below is the code being used

```
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId,      
secretKey));
S3Object object = client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key));
return object.getObjectContent();
```

However the returned object (object.getObjectContent()) has the AWS url, credentials and other details as well.

How to get the file stream alone and write it to the client instead of exposing all the details

1. it leads to security issue
2. it exposed the requested file is being stored in aws with the url being exposed.

Please kindly let us know.

Basically would like the application write the stream retrieved directly to client folder. the stream returned by aws should have only stream content of the file and nothing else.

Comment: Where does the object returned by object.getObjectContent(), which is a S3ObjectInputStream, stores the URL and credentials?

Comment: yes, alex. it contains the actual aws URL and credentials. Not sure whether we need to improper bucket policy or it is the actual behavior. could you please help me

Comment: Observed that it returns stream...and problem is due to conversion of stream to different object......so now the question is if the stream is converted to string or a different object is it possible to read the URL ???